# Android WebView re-rendering UI after changing orientation.

Tags: android, webview, rendering

In My application i am setting orientation of the application on button click, using `setRequestedOrientation()`, My application has one webview which displays local web page.

I am using solution as mentioned in below link, to stop reloading of page when orientation changes.
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/

Only difference is that i am not having `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` in my activity.

What happens in my case is that, my web view does not reload when i change the orientation but it just re-renders the UI upon changing the orientation.

It happens like it first displays the UI and then it displays the white blank screen for few seconds and then again it displays UI.

How can i workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time I used their implementation however I after reading up on the Android documentation I realized that much of their code was pointless since registering for config changes (in the manifest) means that your activity won't be destroyed as it normally is.

Long story short, you don't need to use a `FrameLayout` as a container for your webView, you may not need `onConfigurationChanged`, etc.  If I get some time I will post some code as an example.

For now, make sure you have the following in your manifest file

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

instead of

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

since on orientation change devices may get get a screenSize change

**EDIT** This is what I have done (skimmed from one of my projects so I may have missed minor details)

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.WebWrapperActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

web_wrapper_activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_wrapper_activity_web_view"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity (or a portion of it)

```
public class WebWrapperActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView _webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_wrapper_activity_layout);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        _webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_wrapper_activity_web_view);
        _webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        _webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        _webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        _webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        _webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        _webView.loadUrl(“http://www.google.com”);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        _webView.saveState(outState);
    }
}
```

As i mentioned previously, you may not need `onConfigurationChanged` if your webView is the only view in the Activity.

If you have any issues let me know